# Windows Wingding fonts on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, fonts, update-manager

I would like to use my MetaTrader4 app with Windows-based fonts which requires Wingdings (arrow, thumbs-up, etc.) on my Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to install it from terminal first and it gave me a 'no installation candidate error'.

I saw in another old (Ubuntu 14.04) Ask Ubuntu question how to solve it with these codes, so I tried these codes too:

```
echo "deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multiverse.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

[image: warning printscreen]

As you can see from my screenshot with these deb codes, it's giving me an error message.

Comment: would `Emote` serve this purpose for you?  Download from Ubuntu Software and use Ctrl+Alt+e to invoke and search.  

Comment: You can install all core Microsoft fonts with `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (alongside with useful codecs). I don't know where you got those instructions from but they're patently wrong, "trusty" refers to an aold and unsupported Ubuntu release, 14.04 (that means April 2014!). So, the first thing to do is remove those additional and wrong repos you added. Then learn the lesson NOT to use command you don't understand blindly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes i deleted the old repos. Even if I added Multiverse repo to be able to install ubuntu-restricted-extras it was unable to locate package, also when i tried 'killall the update-manager' trick. Lesson learned but I am still without the fonts.

Comment: Either package exist in the repository. So, you have other problems. You should do `sudo apt update` and check the error messages.

Comment: No error there, so i am stucked (i made the installation with sudo apt update before it too)  I try to search for more maybe i find something to make it work. Thank you

Comment: The package is in multiverse, so if that is active, it should install. Check in "Software&Updates", first tab, if multiverse is enabled. Also check on the second tab whether third party software sources are enabled, and if that is the case, disable them if you do not know the source is suited for your current Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thank you guys! You are GODs! : ) It wasn't enabled, now I have ubuntu-restricted-extras working! Only left that to somehow copy the fonts to Wine to see it and MT4 too.
Finally I found that its a common problem that you should copy the fonts after the installation of Wine and MT4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)